# Visually appealing way to fit in large table? (lit. review style)

Tags: tables, size

I am trying to fit a "large" (that is from the *width* perspective) table on my page.
I found out that the "adjust box" commands come in handy to center a large table:

```
\begin{adjustbox}{center}
\scalebox{0.55}{
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllllll@{}}
\toprule
No. & Source                                                                                                                                      & Target countries & Model              & Specificities                                                                                                                                                                          & Estimated damage                                                                                      & Data                                                                 \\ \midrule
1   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Bonfour, et al. (2018)\\ Macro estimates of \\ intangibles cyber-risks\end{tabular}                              & US, UK           & DIIM Model         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Cyber attack targeted\\ towards financial services\\ and IT sector \\ \\ Additionally estimates intangible\\ costs through econometric methods\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Direct US: $129 BN - $144 BN \\ \\ Direct UK: $28 BN - $58 BN\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}OECD data, \\ Compustat data\end{tabular} \\
2   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}RAND Cooperation \\ (2018) Estimating the \\ Global Cost of Cyber Risk: \\ Methodology and Examples\end{tabular} & 63 Countries     & Leontief I-O Model & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}I-O model to estimate systemic costs\\ \\ Econometric techniques and expert \\ judgement to estimate exposure at risk\end{tabular}                          & \$799 BN                                                                                              & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}OECD data, \\ Financial data\end{tabular} \\
3   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Eling, et al. (2022) \\ The Economic Impact of\\ Extreme Cyber Risk Scenarios\end{tabular}                       & US               & DIIM Model         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Transparent taxonomy of six cyber \\ attack scenarios  \\ \\ Targeted sectors dependend on type of\\ attack\end{tabular}                                    & $0.7 BN - $35 BN                                                                                      & OECD data                                                            \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{adjustbox}
```

Which makes it look like this:

[image]

Nonetheless, when looking at the whole page, the placement of the table looks kind of akward. I played around with \scalebox{0.55} and found that 0.55 is the best tradeoff between not being too small and still fitting somewhat symmetrically below the headline.

I am just thinking: is there a better way to place this table? Might be with a slightly bigger font, since compared to the main text it is really small. On top of that, it just does not look really visually appealing.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Off-topic: The name of the research think thank is "RAND Corporation", not "RAND Cooperation". And, do remember to write `\$`, not `$`, to generate a dollar symbol.

Comment: Thank you very much! Did not proofread yet

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest that you employ a `tabularx` environment and allow automatic line-breaking in 6 of the 7 columns of the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}

\noindent
% 1.15+0.65+0.55+1.7+1.05+0.9 = 6 = # of L columns
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l L{1.15} L{0.65} L{0.55} L{1.7} L{1.05} L{0.9} @{}}
\toprule
No. & Source & Target countries & Model & Specificities & Estimated damage & Data \\ 
\midrule
1 
& Bonfour et al.\ (2018). Macro estimates of intangible cyber-risks 
& US, UK 
& DIIM 
& Cyber attack targeted towards financial services and IT sector. Additionally estimates intangible costs through econometric methods 
& Direct US: \$129--\$144 bn. Direct~UK: \$28--\$58 bn 
& OECD data, Compustat data \\
\addlinespace
2 
& RAND Corporation (2018). Estimating the global cost of cyber risk: Methodology and examples 
& 63 countries 
& Leontief I-O 
& I-O model to estimate systemic costs. Econometric techniques and expert judgement to estimate exposure at risk 
& \$799 bn 
& OECD data, Financial data \\
\addlinespace
3 
& Eling et al.\ (2022). The economic impact of extreme cyber risk scenarios 
& US 
& DIIM 
& Transparent taxonomy of six cyber attack scenarios. Targeted sectors dependend on type of attack 
& \$0.7--\$35 bn 
& OECD data \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative to Mico's answer. Using the `tabularray` package. Here `A[-3]`, for instance, indicates that the ratio of width of this particular column and the last column (which is simply of type `A`) will be at most 3. Refer to documentation of `tabularray` (and also `tabu`) package(s) for more details.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \NewColumnType{A}[1][]{Q[l,t,co=1,#1]}
    \begin{tblr}{%
        colspec={l A[-3] A[-1.5] A[-1.5] A[-3.5] A[-1.75] A},
        row{1}={valign=m},
    }
        \toprule
        No. & Source & Target countries & Model & Specificities & Estimated damage & Data \\ 
        \midrule
        1 
        & Bonfour et al.\ (2018). Macro estimates of intangible cyber-risks 
        & US, UK 
        & DIIM 
        & Cyber attack targeted towards financial services and IT sector. Additionally estimates intangible costs through econometric methods 
        & Direct US: \$129--\$144 bn. Direct~UK: \$28--\$58 bn 
        & OECD data, Compustat data \\
        \addlinespace
        2 
        & RAND Corporation (2018). Estimating the global cost of cyber risk: Methodology and examples 
        & 63 countries 
        & Leontief I-O 
        & I-O model to estimate systemic costs. Econometric techniques and expert judgement to estimate exposure at risk 
        & \$799 bn 
        & OECD data, Financial data \\
        \addlinespace
        3 
        & Eling et al.\ (2022). The economic impact of extreme cyber risk scenarios 
        & US 
        & DIIM 
        & Transparent taxonomy of six cyber attack scenarios. Targeted sectors dependend on type of attack 
        & \$0.7--\$35 bn 
        & OECD data \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This seems very promising indeed. However, when I try to load it in my document I get tons of error messages. Am I missing something? I've loaded all the packages.

Comment: @HansD. With the last tabularray's version 2022D (2022-11-01), it works fine for me.

Comment: @HansD. can you check your package version? `booktabs` support was added in version 2021L: https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/wiki/ChangeLog#2021-07-01-version-2021l.